# Episerver 7.18 : Hide\Show a Block\Page properties on condition

Tags: episerver

I am using EPIServer 7 CMS. I have a requirement in block setup and its properties assignment in Edit mode for which I am trying to find the solution.

Scenario :

- Created a Block Type which have 3 properties - Type, Input1, Input2
- Type is a dropdown. Values are pupulated from enum. Values are Value1 and Value2

Requirement :

- From Type when I select value "Value1" then I only need property "Input1" to be visible.
- And from Type when I select value "Value2" then I need both properties "Input1" and "Input2" to be visible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you need this in Edit Mode's Forms Editing. There is no built-in support for hiding other property fields from a property depending on it's value.

A workaround would be to have own block types for "Value1" and "Value2" and let the editor make the choice when creating the block.

Answer (score 0):

There has been written a blogpost a world.episerver.com that might help you with this: http://world.episerver.com/Blogs/Duong-Nguyen/Dates/2014/1/Country-Region-drop-down-lists-in-All-properties-mode/